# Is the intersection of a finite collection of open sets a union of a subset of the set?

Tags: real-analysis

It might sound silly but I wanted to  know if this definition is true.

Consider a set of set $ \mathbb X$ such that $ \mathbb X$ consists of  $X$
so $ \mathbb X = \{X\} \implies \bigcup \mathbb X = X$. Now, can we suggest that if a collection of finite open sets $ \mathbb B$ has a non empty intersection then the intersection is a union of a set $B$ where $B\subseteq  \mathbb B$?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this... is there any connection between $\mathbb{B}$ and $\mathbb{X}$? You say to consider $\mathbb{X}$ such that such-and-such is true, and then you don't mention $\mathbb{X}$ after.

Comment: @JairTaylor My bad, there is no connection, I was just making a point.

Comment: Then the answer is no. Consider $\mathbb{B} = \{(0,2), (1,3)\}$.  Intersection is $(1,2)$ which is not a union of sets in $\mathbb{B}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Of course, how could I not have seen it. Thank you!

Comment: OK, I've put it as an answer.  In general, it's a good idea to consider the simplest examples first :)

Comment: @JairTaylor I agree, I'll learn to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider $\mathbb{B} = \{(0,2), (1,3)\}$. The intersection is $(1,2)$ which is not a union of sets in $\mathbb{B}.$